# Logging configuration in sailsjs

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I've started to use sailsjs not long ago and really love it ! (I'm a previous rails lover).
Anyway, I do not find the documentation on how to configure the logger transport (I'd like my log to be written in a file within the logs folder, and also to remove the console transport).

Usually, when using winston I use something like:

```
// Add transport file
winston.add(winston.transports.File, {
    filename: some_filename
});

// Handle exceptions
winston.handleExceptions(new winston.transports.File({
    filename: another_filename
}));
```

As sails already wraps Winston, I'm not sure how to do it in a clean way. Any idea or pointer towards an example ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20480373/sails-logging-to-file/20522940#20522940

Comment: Thanks a lot, I did not find this one.