# Sails.js logging system

Tags: logging, sails.js

I need to implement logging to our sails server. 
I have found [sails logging to file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20480373/sails-logging-to-file)

But I am afraid I don't understand it very well.
Intention is to replace console.log with log system.

This is just one example of many places where I need to implement logger:

```
  s3.putObject(params, function (err, data) {
                        if (err)
                            console.log(err);
                        else                         
                            console.log("Successfully uploaded " +
```

//etc

Comment: This might sound silly, but I would really like to use logger if it exists, rather then making my own... even thought making my own sounds tempting :)

Comment: It looks like the question you linked to tells you exactly how to make `console.log` log to a file instead of the screen. Is there something else you're looking to do?

Comment: Does it mean that all of the console.logs that I have in application, such as in my example will be written to a file instead to screen? Given that I do what is instructed in that post? Or if not... how do I use it? warn("My warning here") / error("My error here")...

Comment: Actually, looking at that answer more closely it looks like it relates to the Sails logger, so you'd want to do `sails.log` or `sails.log.warn`, `sails.log.info`, etc., but yes--just follow those instructions.

Comment: Scott would you please make your answer so I can vote it? :)

Comment: Actually someone beat you to it--but you can just go [vote for this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22591861/how-to-log-in-sailsjs/22592079#22592079) and then delete this question :)

Comment: Voted on the other thread :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put this in your config/log.js

```
var winston = require('winston');
var customLogger = new winston.createLogger();

// A console transport logging debug and above.
customLogger.add(new winston.transports.Console, {
  level: 'debug',
  colorize: true
});

// A file based transport logging only errors formatted as json.
customLogger.add(new winston.transports.File({
  level: 'error',
  filename: './error.log',
  json: true,
  colorize: true
}));

module.exports.log = {
  // Pass in our custom logger, and pass all log levels through.
  custom: customLogger,
  level: 'silly',

  // Disable captain's log so it doesn't prefix or stringify our meta data.
  inspect: false
};
```

now whenever you call sails.log.error() it will list your log in error.log file

```
sails.log.error("Error demo message");
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `sails.log.error()`, `sails.log.warn()`, `sails.log.verbose()`, etc to send logs to the console, or even to a file if you configure so in the `config/logs.js` file. There you can also specify the level of log to get in the output, or you can do it passing parameters in the sails command line (`--verbose`).

Comment: for more information check out http://beta.sailsjs.org/#/documentation/reference/Logs/sails.log.html (sails v0.10.x) or http://sailsjs.org/#!documentation/config.log (sails v0.9.x)

Comment: How would you send logs to a file?

Answer (score 1):

I have used `sails.log("message")`, `sails.log.debug("message or variable")`, `sails.log.error("error message or variable")`.