# How to Log in SailsJS

Tags: sails.js, waterline

What is the actual syntax to log in SailsJS?

Docs don't have anything, but found the following line in the site's roadmap

> "Pull out Sails.log (winston wrapper) as a separate module so it can
>   be used by waterline"

I image it's something like:

```
Sails.log(...)
Sails.error(...)
Sails.warn(...)
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

In your controllers, models, services, and anywhere else that the `sails` global is available, you can log with one of:

```
sails.log();
sails.log.warn();
sails.log.info();
sails.log.debug();
sails.log.error();
sails.log.verbose();
sails.log.silly();
```

The logging level (that is, the level at which logs will be output to the console) is set in `/config/log.js`.

Comment: Also remember that you need to set which level to log, or use a command line parameter (like --verbose).

Comment: Any way to get the line number of the log

Answer (score 4):

To extend on the Scott Answer, dont forget to add the filePath: property to log.js file... otherwise it will not work :)

So it should be something like:

```
log: {
level: 'info',
maxSize: 1000,
filePath: 'c://serverlogs/mylogfilename.log'
```

Answer is changed based on Joseph question.

Comment: Which location the log file is created? I tried filePath: '~/name.log'; filePath: 'name.log'. But the files are not created though I can see the log messages in the console. I'm using 0.10.0-rc5.

Comment: @Joseph please take a look at the previous answer. I have updated it. Hope it helps.

Comment: Mine is not created too even specifying filePath. My sails version is 0.10.0-rc7

Comment: I found the solution. The filePath only worked for under 0.10. For >0.9, please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25211183/sails-js-0-10-x-log-to-file