# Sails.js 0.10.x: Log to file

Tags: node.js, logging, sails.js, error-logging

I want to use the built in Sails.js logger and log everything to a file. The "filePath" variable used to work in 0.9.x in config/log.js, but it no longer appears to work in 0.10.x. Has this feature been removed - if so, what's the best way to log to disk now?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

For logging, Sails.js (>= 0.10.0) relies on [captains-log](https://github.com/balderdashy/captains-log), a "lightweight logger with a simple pass-through configuration for use with fancier logging libraries."

To log to a file, you need to configure a custom logger. I would suggest you use [Winston](https://github.com/flatiron/winston), and configure it with the [File Transport](https://github.com/flatiron/winston/blob/master/docs/transports.md#file-transport). This is relatively easy to do:

### Install winston

```
$ npm install winston --save
```

### In your app, edit the config/log.js file and add the following content

```
var winston = require('winston');

var customLogger = new winston.Logger({
    transports: [
        new(winston.transports.File)({
            level: 'debug',
            filename: './logs/my_log_file.log'
        }),
    ],
});

module.exports.log = {
    colors: false,  // To get clean logs without prefixes or color codings
    custom: customLogger
};
```

### Log any messages with the standard sails log command

```
sails.log.debug("Message to be logged");
```

### Restart sails

```
$ sails lift
```

You should see content getting stored in your ./logs/my_log_file.log file.

Comment: why do you have to restart the server to see the logs dumped to a file?  Also if I call sails.log.info('whatever') from the sails console I see nothing on standard out and nothing in the file.  Same for calling it from my application code.  Any idea what's broken?

Comment: Do you know how to enable/disable color through multiple transports? I want file clean and console with colors.

Comment: Use winston@2.4.3 otherwise you will get error winston.Logger is not a constructor.