# Why do my express.js sessions not save in Safari?

Tags: node.js, cookies, express, safari, sails.js

we're working on a sails.js web app where we want session to persist indefinitely.  (As far as I know, in sails that's what they do if we don't make any settings.)

The session persists (that is, the user is automatically logged in) in every browser except Safari (both iOS and OSX).

I tried changing the sails session settings for a 24-hour session as follows:

```
cookie: {
 maxAge: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000
},
```

but still the user name disappears from the web page in Safari, but persists everywhere else.

We are going to display the HTML in an iOS app; is there a setting to be made in the app environment maybe?

thanks!

Comment: Any messages in the sails log? Is the session store correctly configured? (I think you still need that at least, even if sails.js handles the rest).

Comment: Hi Ben! We're using the Redis store.  And the session works in the other browsers, and it DOES work in OSX Safari as long as you don't terminate it.  Which sails log exactly?  I'll check it.

Comment: sails.js has a log option. You can read more about it, and how to configure it, in this question and set of answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25211183/sails-js-0-10-x-log-to-file As to your issue, it definitely sounds cookie-related